# SVG transform property

Tags: html, animation, svg, velocity.js

I am having some issues with transforming an SVG. What I am trying to do is have a rotated rectangle scale and move at the same time. So far I have not found a way to do this..

Situation is as follows:

I have a rectangle defined in HTML like this so it rotates around its center:

```
<rect class="rotate_rect" id="right_left_polyg" x="50" y="35" width="12" height="12" style="fill:#4A4A4A;stroke:#4A4A4A;stroke-width:2" transform="rotate(45,56,41)"/>
```

I use velocity.js as my animation library, but the problem is more of a general nature. Issue is that when I try to move the rectangle to the right it moves down to the right. This is because my x-value I am changing, is also contained in the rotate function.

I also tried the following, but this does not react as I hoped.

```
.rotate_rect{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

Is there a way I can define a rotate function without having to specify the x-value?

To make it easily reproducable, here is my rectangle.. I have defined the class as above..

```
<rect class="rotate_rect" id="right_left_polyg" x="50" y="35" width="12" height="12" style="fill:#4A4A4A;stroke:#4A4A4A;stroke-width:2"/>
```

Is there a way to do this so the rectangle rotates around its center axis and x-value stays out of the rotate function?

Answer (score 1):

Build the rectangle so that its center is at `0, 0` and use `translate()` to move it before rotating it. (Technically moving *after* rotating due to transform semantics having operations applied from the innermost to the outermost.)

For example:

```
<rect x="-6" y="-6" width="12" height="12" transform="translate(56,41) rotate(45)" class="rotate_rect" id="right_left_polyg" style="fill:#4A4A4A;stroke:#4A4A4A;stroke-width:2" />
```

Or:

```
<g transform="translate(56,41)">
  <rect x="-6" y="-6" width="12" height="12" transform="rotate(45)" class="rotate_rect" id="right_left_polyg" style="fill:#4A4A4A;stroke:#4A4A4A;stroke-width:2" />
</g>
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it functions, still there is an issue in the interaction with my animation library Velocity.js. Velocity uses other attributes for the translate and rotate properties of transformation. Therefore you get jumps in animation. Solution found in setting an initial value in Velocity and then animating this..